# casting (AS) in Kotlin , Not Working on objects

Tags: kotlin, casting

```
open class Operations1(){
    open fun sum1(n1:Int,n2:Int):Int{
        return n1+n2
    }

    fun div(n1:Int,n2:Int):Int{
        return n1/n2
    }
}


class Operations2:Operations1{
    constructor():super(){

    }

    override fun sum1(n1:Int,n2:Int):Int{
        return n1*n2
    }

    fun mul(n1:Int,n2:Int):Int{
        return n1*n2
    }

    fun sub(n1:Int,n2:Int):Int{
        return n1-n2
    }
}

fun main(){

    var op2 = Operations2()
    println("Operation 2: "+op2.sum1(9,9)) // output 81
    var op1 = Operations1()

    println("Operation 1: "+op1.sum1(9,9)) //output 18

    //  THIS SHOULD HAVE DONE CASTING
    // AND SHOULD HAVE CALLED SUM1 FUNCTION OF OPERATIONS1
    // BUT IT IS NOT WORKING
    var opas = Operations2() as Operations1

    println("opas :"+opas.sum1(9,9))        //What should be the output ? 18 or 81

}
```

Comment: With casting or not - overloaded function will be called. So the expected output is *81*

Comment: You've set the class of the reference variable (`opas`) to `Operations1`. But the actual object it refers to is still an `Operations2`, because that's what you created. And instance methods, such as `sum1`, are called based on the object's class.

Comment: is there any way to call operations1 sum1 using operations2 object.

Comment: You can add a method to `Operations2` that calls a `super` method. But before you do this you should consider whether you actually need this, or if you've just ended up in a situation where you _think_ you need this because of how you've written your code. It would help if you provided a real-world example of where you think you need this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output gonna be 81, It works just fine.

Upd: A cast, instructs the compiler to change the existing type of an object REFERENCE to another type. It can give us some other functionality, but all the methods will still work from Class of created object.

Upd: You may need to read about dynamic polymorphism

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any explantion for why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: is there any way to call operations1 sum1 using operations2 object.

Comment: As I know we can only call super.sum1 from sum1 of Operator2 only. So it's gonna be inside of Operations2 function body. we can make some check in child-class's fun and only call parent's method then return, when needed. Don't know other ways actualy